# Headers already send Magento 2 multistore addon domain

Tags: php, javascript, multistore

Multiple websites are working on Magento 2.2 with the addon domain method and symlinks.

The theme is visible, etc.

Only thing is that at the bottom I see the following message. Looking for advice.

```
Exception:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/staging/public_html/vendor\
/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php:114) in /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Std\
lib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 148in /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:6\
1

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Cannot modify h...', '/home2/staging/...', 148, \
Array)
#1 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(148): setcookie('X-Magento-Var\
y', '5c0fe9cddef92d0...', 0, '/', '', false, true)
#2 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(101): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\
\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setCookie('X-Magento-Vary', '5c0fe9cddef92d0...', Array)
#3 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/Http.php(95): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCoo\
kieManager->setSensitiveCookie('X-Magento-Vary', '5c0fe9cddef92d0...', Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\SensitiveC\
ookieMetadata))
#4 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/Response/HttpPlugin.php(25): Magento\Framework\\
App\Response\Http->sendVary()
#5 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\Re\
sponse\HttpPlugin->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#6 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Response\
\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#7 /home2/staging/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\\
App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#8 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Intercepto\
r->sendResponse()
#9 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMod\
e(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException))
#10 /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchExcepti\
on(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException))
#11 /home2/staging/…………………………………/index.php(143): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)\
)
#12 {main}
```